# How to reverse route to an action from my form in Play Framework 2.3

Tags: java, playframework-2.3

Good day Everyone,

I am new to Play framework and am trying to get started building an application. Under the `app/controllers` folders i have created sub packages so i have something like `app/controllers/products/ProductController.class`.

In my `routes.conf` file i have added a sample route like this

`GET   /createproduct  controllers.products.ProductController.listAllProducts()
POST   /createproduct  controllers.products.ProductController.createProductDetail()`

and i can goto the url `http://localhost:9000/createproduct` and see a sample view that i created.

My issue now is that i want to add a form to the view and when i try to use the form helper method to POST data to the POST URL above from my new view like this

`@helper.form(action = routes.products.ProductController.createProductDetail()) {`

i get the error that

`value products is not a member of object controllers.routes`

All the samples that i saw online only use the route.Application example  which is doesnt fit my issue.

So my question is how do i reverse route to this action or route from a view using the Form helper

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The valid syntax is:

```
[full-package-name].routes.[controller].[method]
```

So in your case it should be

```
 controllers.products.routes.ProductController.createProductDetail()
```

`controllers.routes` is imported implicity, therefore for using with controllers in default package you can short it to:

```
routes.Controller.action()
```

Comment: Wow! That should really be documented.